# requests + bs4 no results from pages

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.5

Here the code that can get info from https://www.gabar.org/membersearchresults.cfm

but cannot from https://www.gabar.org/membersearchresults.cfm?start=1&id=70FFBD1B-9C8E-9913-79DBB8B989DED6C1

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import traceback


links_to_visit = []
navigation_links = []  # for testing next button

base_url = 'https://www.gabar.org'


def make_soup(link):
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup


def all_results(url):
    global links_to_visit
    global navigation_links
    soup = make_soup(url)
    print(soup)
    div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'cs_control'})
    links = div.find_all('a')
    print(links)
    for link in links:
        try:
            if link.text == 'Next':  # prev, next, new search
                navigation_links.append(link)
                print('got it')
            elif not '/MemberSearchDetail.cfm?ID=' in link.get('href'):
                pass  # I dont need that link
            else:
                links_to_visit.append(link)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
    print(len(links_to_visit))
    print(links_to_visit)
    #print(links_to_visit[-1].get('href'))


def start():
    flag = 1
    page = 1
    while page < 60716:
        flag = 0
        if navigation_links[-1].text == 'Next':
            flag = 1
            next_link = navigation_links[-1]
            #print(next_link.get('href'))
        page += 25
        print(base_url + next_link.get('href'))
        all_results(base_url + next_link.get('href'))
        print('page is:', page)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_results('https://www.gabar.org/membersearchresults.cfm')
    start()
```

What I need to understand or do if I want to get full result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to understand is that there is more than a URL to an HTTP-request. In this case, a search result is only available to the session that executed the search and can therefore only be paged through if you are the "owner" of that session. Most websites identify a session using session-cookies that you need to send along with your HTTP-request.

This can be a huge hassle, but luckily pythons requests takes care of all of that for you with `requests.session`. Instead of using `requests.get(url)` you initialize the session `session=requests.session()` and then use that session in subsequent requests `session.get(url)`. This will automagically preserve cookies for you and in many ways behave like an actual browser would.

You can read more about how requests.session works [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects).

And last but not least, your fixed code =)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import traceback


links_to_visit = []
navigation_links = []  # for testing next button
# we initialize the session here
session = requests.session()

base_url = 'https://www.gabar.org'


def make_soup(link):
    # r = requests.get(link)
    # we use the session here in order to preserve cookies across requests
    r = session.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup


def all_results(url):
    # globals are almost never needed or recommended and certainly not here.
    # you can just leave this out
    # global links_to_visit
    # global navigation_links
    soup = make_soup(url)
    print(soup)
    div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'cs_control'})
    links = div.find_all('a')
    print(links)
    for link in links:
        try:
            if link.text == 'Next':  # prev, next, new search
                navigation_links.append(link)
                print('got it')
            elif not '/MemberSearchDetail.cfm?ID=' in link.get('href'):
                pass  # I dont need that link
            else:
                links_to_visit.append(link)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
    print(len(links_to_visit))
    print(links_to_visit)
    #print(links_to_visit[-1].get('href'))


def start():
    flag = 1
    page = 1
    while page < 60716:
        flag = 0
        if navigation_links[-1].text == 'Next':
            flag = 1
            next_link = navigation_links[-1]
            #print(next_link.get('href'))
        page += 25
        print(base_url + next_link.get('href'))
        all_results(base_url + next_link.get('href'))
        print('page is:', page)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_results('https://www.gabar.org/membersearchresults.cfm')
    start()
```